# How to prove this because if we consider big-oh than logn^2 <= log n + 5 can never happen if n grows?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, asymptotics, big-o-notation

f(n) = log n^2; g(n) = log n + 5   =>  f(n) = Θ (g(n))

I think we can prove this for omega but how can we prove it for Big oh ?

because if we simplify it to logn + logn <= logn +5 => logn<=5 is not true !

Answer (score 0):

To show $f(n) = O(g(n))$ pick $n_0 = 1$ and $c=2$. Then, for any $n \ge n_0$,
$$
f(n) = \log n^2 = 2 \log n < 2 \log n + 10 = 2(\log n+5) = c g(n).
$$

For the opposite direction (i.e., $g(n) = O(f(n))$) pick $n_0 = 2^5$ and $c=1$. For any $n \ge n_0$:
$$
g(n) = \log n +5 = \log n + \log 2^5 = \log 2^5n \le \log n^2 = c f(n).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $$2\log(n)\le 2(\log(n)+5)$$ for all $n$, so

$$\log(n^2)=O(\log(n)+5).$$

---

The $\Omega$ bound is slightly more difficult, as it does not hold for all $n$:

$$\log(n)+5\le2\log(n)$$ only for $n\ge e^5$.

(More generally, $c(\log(n)+5)\le 2\log(n)\iff n\ge e^{ 5c/(2-c)}\land c<2$.)